@ngstack/code-editor Code Editor Component for Angular. How to Edit C#, Java, Javascript Code
I have recently integrated the @ngstack/code-editor in my angular app. But I can't seem to figure out how to edit other programming languages code.
  codeModel: CodeModel = {
    language: 'json',
    uri: 'main.json',
    value: '{}'
  };

I can put the word C# in the language property but what goes in the uri property?
